# Is '\2' a sort of escape sequence in Python, akin to '\b' for backspace or '\n' for newline?

Tags: python-3.x, escaping

I was trying to open a file in a folder whose name starts with the number 2. The file name argument obviously had a sequence of characters which went like **`C:\....\2999abc...\abc.xlsx`**, when I received a file not found error.

Post this, through trial and error, I found that **`\2`** is getting treated as an escape sequence and adding a **`\`** before **`\299..`** solves it. Some more trial and error results are as below:

```
a = 'assdd\2ddd'
print (a)
Result: assdd ddd

a = 'assdd\1ddd'
print (a)
Result: assddddd
```

Can somebody help me understand what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

In a `Python` string, escape character and number together is interpreted as an ASCII character with the number as octal value.

In your case, `\2` is treated as ASCII character with octal value, 002, which is the `Start of Text` (`STX`) character. `\1` is the `Start of Header` (`SOH`) character.

In ASCII characters, characters with octal values 000-037 are non-printable, and you are not supposed to print them out. If you do call `print` function on them in `Python`, as you see, `Python` prints `\2` as a space, `\1` as empty. However, this may differ on different machines.

Comment: [In a string literal, these escapes denote a Unicode character with the given value.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). So, Unicode, not ASCII.